# Crystal Reports Rounding Issues

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi, rounding

I'm working on creating a report in Crystal reports that is summarizing customers that were activated and deactivated in the same year. My report is looking something like this:

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>Customer</td>
    <td>Create Date</td>
    <td>End Date</td>
    <td>Days Active</td>
    <td>Months Billed</td>
    <td>Invoice Amount</td>
    <td>Average Invoice Amount</td>
    <td>3 Year Lost Revenue</td>
    <td>5 Year Lost Revenue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Customer 1</td>
    <td>11/20/2014</td>
    <td>08/05/2015</td>
    <td>258</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>$2200.00</td>
    <td>$244.44</td>
    <td>$6600.00</td>
    <td>$12466.67</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Basically the problem I'm having is the 3 year and 5 year lost revenue are not rounding properly.

I'll explain how I'm calculating everything and maybe someone can explain why those 2 columns are rounding weird.

Ok so customer, create date, and end date are all pulled from a database table.

Days Active = End Date - Created Date
Months Billed = Ceiling(Days Active/30)

For invoice amount I have a formula that basically says:

if isnull(column in the table I'm pulling from) then 0 

else running sum total for the column with the Invoices in it

Average Invoice Amount = Invoice Amount / Months Billed

3 Year Lost Revenue = (36*Average Invoice Amount) - Invoice Amount 
5 Year Lost Revenue = (60*Average Invoice Amount) - Invoice Amount

The numbers I used in my table for Invoice Amount, Avg Invoice and the 3 and 5 year revenue are actual numbers I'm getting. So the months billed, invoice amount and average invoice amount are all correct. 
But as you can see
 
($244.44 * 36) - $2200 = $6599.84 
($244.44 * 60) - $2200 = $12466.40

Both these columns are formatted the same too but somehow they're both rounding differently...any idea what I'm doing to make it round like this?

Thanks!

Comment: After you have placed the fields on the report, right click them and Select Format Object -> Then you can either select one of the available formats or enter a Custom Style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely forgot to round intermediate value of `Average Invoice Amount`. 2200/9=244.4444444..., but your manual calculation uses just 244.44 - sure results will differ.

Comment: I have everything rounding the same way, 1.00 for decimals and the rounding is 0.001. The weird thing thats throwing me off is the 3 year and 5 year lost revenue is all off by a couple cents, but not consistently. Like one result is off by 4 cents, one is off by 20 cents, one is off by 10 cents

Comment: Problem is not in visual rounding, problem is inside calculation. You need to use `Average Invoice Amount = Round(Invoice Amount / Months Billed, 2)` or something - my syntax may be bit off.

Comment: Yea I see what you're saying and I found my problem, when I was checking the calculations I was just using the number in the Avg Invoice Amount column and that gives a different answer because the 3 year and 5 year loss formulas use the non rounded answer for the average

Answer (score 0):

Rather than you apply new logic that why this happened, you simply format decimal field by formatting the field. Crystal report have feature to format field as per data-type of field.

This below text taken from this [link](http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=17997)

Actually, you can select the field in a text box, right click, and format it.  However, here's a better way of doing percentages.

1. Put the number field on the report.
2. Right-click and format.
3. On the Number tab, click on the Customize button.
4. On the Number tab, set the number of decimal places.
5. On the Currency Symbol tab, Enable the currency symbol, Set the Position to the right side of the number, and change "$" to "%".

This will give you the percent sign without having to use a text box.

[Check this link too for visualizing](http://crystaltricks.com/wordpress/?p=163)

https://www.webucator.com/blog/2010/05/crystal-reports-rounding-function/